# Changing position with css avoiding flexbox and javascript (append, insertAfter)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm building a template and I want to move an element avoiding flexbox if it is possible, using pure css.

Here's my problem:

```html
<div class="container-fluid health-details">
 <div class="row">
  <?php include 'sidebar.php';?>
  <div class="col-md-8">
   <div class="information">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam neque magna, volutpat ut scelerisque gravida, posuere nec diam. Fusce et ligula eget nisi malesuada dictum. Nunc et purus massa. </p>

    <p>Curabitur vel fermentum nisi. Aenean elementum vel erat sit amet viverra. Ut quis sapien at dolor sollicitudin ullamcorper. Aliquam quis volutpat nisl, nec cursus tortor. Proin elementum magna nec erat ultricies, eu feugiat nunc convallis. Sed dapibus nec eros in porttitor. In finibus sed dolor vel ornare. </p>

    <p>Aenean volutpat iaculis ullamcorper. Integer id nisi fringilla, feugiat est quis, hendrerit felis. Aliquam nunc justo, feugiat quis ligula ac, rhoncus pellentesque sapien. Pellentesque gravida dui elit, at egestas libero suscipit quis. Sed consectetur, tellus in faucibus rhoncus, nisl ipsum pulvinar magna, posuere pulvinar nulla urna a nisl. Quisque cursus ac metus et venenatis. </p>
    <p>Pellentesque vehicula ornare quam, id tempus felis volutpat quis. Proin volutpat massa ac turpis dignissim, id consectetur eros sagittis. Pellentesque in interdum turpis. Maecenas eget nisi sit amet nisi pretium placerat. Maecenas luctus vel leo ut fermentum. Nullam ullamcorper ultrices scelerisque. Cras semper eros vitae nisi vulputate euismod. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam urna sem, vulputate in hendrerit a, imperdiet at ipsum. Integer aliquet arcu erat, interdum consectetur enim condimentum sed.</p>

    <p>Integer egestas dolor eu sagittis pharetra. Phasellus non commodo magna. Maecenas sit amet libero pellentesque arcu posuere ultrices ut non augue. Donec aliquam pellentesque lectus, vel sollicitudin nisi viverra at. Fusce convallis velit eget urna ullamcorper finibus. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque ac eros vel ligula vulputate aliquet vestibulum sit amet nisl. Nunc rutrum blandit consectetur. Pellentesque vel rhoncus eros. Nam non vestibulum ex, sed cursus sem. Suspendisse ut porttitor erat, nec placerat ligula. Cras consequat ut ligula posuere interdum. Phasellus porta, nisi quis pharetra fringilla, nulla sem convallis sapien, ut faucibus ipsum mauris nec nibh. Maecenas efficitur hendrerit eros, vel vulputate nisi convallis nec. Aliquam pulvinar scelerisque mi, et placerat nisi egestas eget.</p>

   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

My sidebar is really easy, something like:

```html
<aside>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Ciao</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Ciao Program</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Program Outline</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tuition &amp; Fees Guide</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Admission Policy</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </aside>
```

What I'd like to do is, on mobile switch the position of the sidebar and put it within the blurb:

```html
<div class="container-fluid health-details">
 <div class="row">
  
  <div class="col-md-8">
   <div class="information">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam neque magna, volutpat ut scelerisque gravida, posuere nec diam. Fusce et ligula eget nisi malesuada dictum. Nunc et purus massa. </p>

    <p>Curabitur vel fermentum nisi. Aenean elementum vel erat sit amet viverra. Ut quis sapien at dolor sollicitudin ullamcorper. Aliquam quis volutpat nisl, nec cursus tortor. Proin elementum magna nec erat ultricies, eu feugiat nunc convallis. Sed dapibus nec eros in porttitor. In finibus sed dolor vel ornare. </p>
    <?php include 'sidebar.php';?>
    <p>Aenean volutpat iaculis ullamcorper. Integer id nisi fringilla, feugiat est quis, hendrerit felis. Aliquam nunc justo, feugiat quis ligula ac, rhoncus pellentesque sapien. Pellentesque gravida dui elit, at egestas libero suscipit quis. Sed consectetur, tellus in faucibus rhoncus, nisl ipsum pulvinar magna, posuere pulvinar nulla urna a nisl. Quisque cursus ac metus et venenatis. </p>
    <p>Pellentesque vehicula ornare quam, id tempus felis volutpat quis. Proin volutpat massa ac turpis dignissim, id consectetur eros sagittis. Pellentesque in interdum turpis. Maecenas eget nisi sit amet nisi pretium placerat. Maecenas luctus vel leo ut fermentum. Nullam ullamcorper ultrices scelerisque. Cras semper eros vitae nisi vulputate euismod. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam urna sem, vulputate in hendrerit a, imperdiet at ipsum. Integer aliquet arcu erat, interdum consectetur enim condimentum sed.</p>

    <p>Integer egestas dolor eu sagittis pharetra. Phasellus non commodo magna. Maecenas sit amet libero pellentesque arcu posuere ultrices ut non augue. Donec aliquam pellentesque lectus, vel sollicitudin nisi viverra at. Fusce convallis velit eget urna ullamcorper finibus. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque ac eros vel ligula vulputate aliquet vestibulum sit amet nisl. Nunc rutrum blandit consectetur. Pellentesque vel rhoncus eros. Nam non vestibulum ex, sed cursus sem. Suspendisse ut porttitor erat, nec placerat ligula. Cras consequat ut ligula posuere interdum. Phasellus porta, nisi quis pharetra fringilla, nulla sem convallis sapien, ut faucibus ipsum mauris nec nibh. Maecenas efficitur hendrerit eros, vel vulputate nisi convallis nec. Aliquam pulvinar scelerisque mi, et placerat nisi egestas eget.</p>

   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

I don't have to necessarily use php to do the trick, I can do it with simple html. The thing is that I want to avoid to use flexbox, I would be nice if I can only add a class to my sidebar with php. The other thing that I have to avoid is to repeat myself (DRY). Of course I can create the same bar and display:none and block on mobile (so I will have the same two sidebars), but if it is possible I'd rather avoid it.

Is there any solution to solve my problem?

I would avoid to use a script to, like something with javascript (append the element based on the size of the viewport, that's the only method that I know that it will work for sure, something like):

```
$('.sidebar').insertAfter( '.information p:last-child' );
```

I mean, it will work just fine but I don't love to style with javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Use CSS media queries, specifically `max-width`. Something like: `@media (max-width: 768px) { aside { display: none; } }`

Comment: Flexbox:order is the way to solve this. What is your reason not to use flex?